# Quick way of writing equation of a tangent

Tags: calculus

The quick method and the more elaborate one do not reconcile. I must be making a mistake somewhere, mind pointing out?

Equation: $x^2-3y^2=4y$

Tangent to a general point $(x_1,y_1)$ can be written down directly if the quick method is used, and it is: $xx_1-3yy_1=2(y+y_1)$.

However, I can not arrive at the same answer in the following way.

First find derivative: $\frac{d}{dx}(x^2)=\frac{d}{dx}(3y^2+4y)$, i.e. $\displaystyle{\frac{dy}{dx}=\frac{2x}{6y+4}}$.
The general equation of a line: $\displaystyle{m=\frac{y-y_a}{x-x_a}}$. Thus, $\frac{2x_1}{6y_1+4}(x-x_1)=y-y_1$. Which leads to the following result: $xx_1-x_1^2-3yy_1-2y+3y_1^2+2y_1=0$. Which appears to be similar to the quick method, but really is not?

EDIT:

**The quick method and proof:**

In the original equation substitute $x^2$ for $xx_1$, $y^2$ for $yy_1$, $xy$ for $\frac{1}{2}(xx_1+yy_1)$ and $x,y$ for $\frac{1}{2}(x+x_1), \frac{1}{2}(y+y_1)$ respectively.

**For everyone's benefit, here is the proof:**

Consider general second order polynomial from which we derive the rule: 
$$ax^2+by^2+cxy+dx=0$$.

1) Let's find $\frac{d}{dx}y$. Which is $\frac{d}{dx}(ax^2+by^2+cxy+dx)=0$. The derivative is thus: $\displaystyle{\frac{-cy_1-2ax_1-d}{2by_1+cx_1}}$.

2) Insert into a general equation of a line $\displaystyle{\frac{-cy_1-2ax_1-d}{2by_1+cx_1}}(x-x_1)=y-y_1$.

3) Now simplify $(-cy_1-2ax_1-d)(x-x_1)-(y-y_1)(2by_1+cx_1)=0$. Remembering that $2ax_1^2+2by_1^2=-2cx_1y_1-2dx_1$

4) The result: $$(axx_1+byy_1)+\frac{1}{2}c(xy_1+yx_1)+\frac{1}{2}d(x+x_1)=0$$

Comment: I am not familiar with the 'quick method', could you give more information on this?

Comment: That is as "quick" as the process gets, right? If you understand that we can write the equation of the tangent line as : $(y-y_1)=m_{slope} (x-x_1)$ , then just proceed with that.

Comment: i am not sure if this method will work for graphs that are not conic sections.

Comment: I will add the details of the quick method into the body. I have noticed the missed step, but still there is something wrong with signs.

Comment: the "quick method" only works for quadratics. Why would it not work for polynomials of order greater than 2?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are almost in there. 
Since $(x_1,y_1)$ is a point on the curve, it satisfies that

$x_1^2-3y_1^2=4y_1$.

Substitute to your last equation:

$xx_1-x_1^2-3yy_1-2y+3y_1^2+2y_1=xx_1-3yy_1-2y-2y_1-(x_1^2-3y_1^2-4y_1)=0$

to get answer:

$xx_1-3yy_1=2y+2y_1$